# Pass JSON config variable to helm using --set

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-configmap
data:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.envVars }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

Running
`helm upgrade my-app --install --set envVars.CREDS='{"key":"val"}'`
with the above `configmap` results in a configmap as follows:

```
CREDS = ["key":"val"]
```

So instead of a JSON, it's an array.

What do I need to configure to pass it as a JSON?

Comment: I think [`helm --set`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set) can't set keys to an object value, and the escaping is kind of tricky.  I'd suggest writing a separate YAML file and passing it with `helm install -f`.

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine, based on this answer regarding json objects representation in yamls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989696/11874278

If you want to achieve another thing - this key as json string you could do:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-configmap
data:
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.envVars }}
  {{ $key }}: >
    {{ $value }}
  {{- end }}
```