# What is a yaml structure when one line has a dash and other lines at the same level don't?

Tags: yaml

What is this yaml structure from the file [invoice.yaml](https://filesamples.com/formats/YAML)?

```
items:
    - part_no:   A4786
      descrip:   Water Bucket (Filled)
      price:     1.47
      quantity:  4

    - part_no:   E1628
      descrip:   High Heeled "Ruby" Slippers
      size:      8
      price:     133.7
      quantity:  1
```

If items were a list each line would would start with a dash.  The lines without a dash would be key:value pairs in the items dictionary.  But what is the line with the dash, a list of one key:value pair?  I don't see the point of that.

I've seen this structure in lots of YAML files for configuring k8s or cloud, but none of the docs or examples I can find explain what this structure is.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YAML equivalent of array of objects in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989612/yaml-equivalent-of-array-of-objects-in-json)

Answer (score 1):

Found a very good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989612/yaml-equivalent-of-array-of-objects-in-json).  The items is a list of mappings.  In JSON items would be an array of objects.

Comment: Oooh that clears some things up. I was always confused in GitHub actions why some lines in a job started with a dash and others didn't. A JSON example would probably help.